# Hybrid AAD - user ID with cloud only password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have Federated authentication enabled for user sign-in in AAD. Can I create an user account with cloud only password verification in hybrid environment? Please advise.

At the moment, we are facing error AADSTS50126, when getting token using ROPC login.

Answer (score 0):

For a Domain which is federated it won't allow to create user account in cloud with same federated domain and it is created only on on-premises. If you are creating a cloud only user in the Azure Tenant the authentication will happen only in Azure Active Directory.

Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/choose-ad-authn) for the different Authentication methods for Azure Cloud Authentication.

You can go through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/38035/aadsts50126-invalid-grant-error-validating-credent.html) for the error message and see if it helps

Comment: Thank you, My question was, Do Azure AD allows creating a cloud only user in Hybrid setup (PHS)?,  as you mentioned in the link, we do have the same error ( AADSTS50126) for one of the service account in backend job. If Azure AD allows, we can proceed with it (modify it as cloud only account OR create new service account). We do use this service account to make Intune graph API calls for reporting sake.

Comment: @Prasad9avs You can create cloud only users whether it is federated or PHS setup. You can create yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com